How to highlight the query suggestions?
we are using Sitecore 10.1.2 and Coveo for Sitecore 5, we have a page with Coveo searchbox and the searchbox markup is like following:
<label for="keyword">I'm Looking For...</label>
<div class="CoveoSearchbox name" data-placeholder='Enter name or specialty' data-add-search-button='false'
     data-auto-focus='false' data-enable-omnibox="true" data-enable-query-suggest-addon="true" data-query-suggest-character-threshold="3">
    <span class="CoveoFieldSuggestions" data-field="@@fullname" data-prebind-field="fieldTranslator"></span>
    <span class="CoveoFieldSuggestions" data-field="@@doctorcategory" data-prebind-field="fieldTranslator"></span>
</div>

When user type in a keyword in the search box, the query suggestions will be shown after 3 characters to match either the doctor category or full name. we'd like to have the portion of the query suggestion that matches the keyword being hightlighted, such as bold and yellow background, how do I achieve that?
I did not see any javascript code to setup this searchbox, looks like it is part of the coveo search box configuration, by search in coveo documentation, I do not see anywhere mentioned data-enable-omnibox="true" data-enable-query-suggest-addon="true"
Thank you very much in advance!

Hi @John, please share your Sitecore and Coveo version. That will help others to answer/suggest.

Meanwhile, as I read I see the feature present in Headless Coveo https://docs.coveo.com/en/headless/latest/usage/highlighting/ . Do check if something similar is available for your version as well. And you can also contact Coveo Support for suggestions https://connect.coveo.com/s/question/0D56Q00007rvpRISAY/how-can-you-highlight-keywords-in-result-excerpts
